# Meaning and origin of もありか?

Tags: set-phrases

> 精霊の身体は人間より遥かに強靭だからな。毒でも呑ませてみようか。ああ、それならば麻薬を打ってみるの**もありか**……

The speaker was offering some ways to torment a 精霊.

Hi. Does the もありか mean “OK”? But I can only find the word 在り処(ありか), which means “whereabouts” in dictionaries. Does the ありか come from あるか, which indicates existence?

Thank you.

Comment: Do these help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43483/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5121/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4642/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Thank you. I didn’t know there were similar questions. I searched for relevant threads with the key word ありか and found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This もありか is three words, も + あり + か.

- **も** is "also".
- **あり** (also written as アリ, from the masu-stem of 有る) is a noun that roughly means "a good idea", "a possible solution", etc.

  - [Is アリ in そんなのアリかよ⁉︎ some type of slang?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43481/5010)
  - [Understanding ありやな](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4642/5010)
- **か** is a question marker, which in this sentence means "..., I guess".

> ああ、それならば麻薬を打ってみるのもありか……
> Oh, in this case, trying narcotic drugs will be good, too, I guess.